# How to select all divs which have a child of class "test-class"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can one select all divs which have a child whose class is "test-class"?

Wow, this marked as duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector). I read that question and this question is really a duplicate... however, I and I suppose no one will find that badly titled question if she/wants to do what I am described in my title.

1) CSS *has* parent selector but we are seeking from something else

2) That question title would be Is there a CSS *child* selector?

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to select the parent of the .test-class element?

Comment: I don't think you can

Comment: You can't do this with plain CSS, though. With Javascript, you'd be able to.

Comment: A child..."what" (i.e. a child class, a child div element, a child...) once you know what that is, then use jquery to find the locatons and attack.

Comment: Yes, you can do it, just wait 1-2 year for CSS4.

Comment: @dfsq: Funny how there is a lingering misconception about CSS 4 .. CSS 3 is the final version

Comment: @Adrift Yes, and HTML4 was final too.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Please add some HTML to the question, showing an example of an element you'd like to select.

Comment: @DerekHenderson you have totally changed the question; we should ask the OP if what you've written is really what he was asking. The original question was "Targeting all DIVS inside a test-class with at least a son". Please watch your edits carefully...

Comment: @AndreaLigios, are you sure?  I initially posted an answer to this (which I deleted), to which I received comments that I was answering the wrong question and that the question is what I have edited it to.  All I did was change the word "in" to "of" and removed the w3schools link.  Clearly someone agreed with my edit or it would not have passed peer review.

Comment: @dfsq: What does HTML have to do with CSS? Adrift is right, "CSS4" is just a misnomer for "a level 4 CSS module", while "CSS3" is either a misnomer for "a level 3 CSS module", or an umbrella term for everything beyond CSS2. Anyway, given recent changes, you may not even be able to do this in CSS with a level 4 selector anymore - see my comment on the accepted answer in the duplicate link.

Comment: @DerekHenderson yeah I saw your answer, but who commented it saying you was wrong ? Not the OP, but some other guy that probably hadn't understood the question himself :) You should have not erased your imho

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: for clarity of the readers, the original question was

> How can one select all divs that are inside a test-class and which have a child ?

You can't, because in CSS there are not (yet) Parent Selector nor Previous Sibling Selector.

You can only target Next Siblings or Childrens (and then Descendants)...

only *right* and *down*, no *left* and *up*.

As a note, please do not use W3SChools when possible ([read why](http://w3fools.com/)), and for Selectors refer to W3C Official Documentation:

**[CSS2 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)**

**[CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)**

**[CSS4 Selectors - *Draft*](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#overview)**

And when CSS4 will be ready, if it will be like documented now, the proper Selector to do this will be:

> **`E! > F`**
>
> an E element parent of an F element
>
> Determining the subject of a selector + Child combinator

Then you will be able to craft a combinator like

```
.test-class div! > *
```

read as: every `DIV` that have something inside (some children) and is descendant of `test-class`

Comment: W3C or at least [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS).

Comment: @DerekHenderson Added Descendants as suggested by the Edit. For the other edits, they was invalid... there is no way to quote elements inline AFAIK, and Code is a better (and less annoying) higlighter than Bold imho. Finally, you was deleting all my second part of the post :/

Comment: @Andrea Ligios: Whatever your opinion may be, it is simply **wrong** to use code markdown for highlighting things that are not code, much like it is wrong to use a quotation for a code block, or a code block for a quotation. If bold/italics are too much emphasis, don't highlight at all.

Comment: @Derek Henderson: Usually, where backticks are being used for highlighting things that are not code it is sufficient to remove them completely, as I have just done.

Comment: @BoltClock , you should have told me that 400 answers ago :D I will use bold ;)

Comment: Sorry to say but my question was not _ever_ as "How can one select all divs that are inside a test-class and which have a child ?" The only thing I edited in the _title_ was deleteing the gt and lt signs around the div

Answer (score -2):

You can select the childs of the parent-div ("test-class") by number.
So to select all the first childs:

```
.text-class:nth-child{/*code*/}
```

To be sure that all the child divs are being selected (I would do as much as the .text-class div with the most childs):

```
.text-class:nth-child, .text-class:nth-child(2), 
.text-class:nth-child(3), .text-class:nth-child(4){/*code*/}
```

Btw it was in the list, hope its going to work for you!

Comment: `:nth-child` is not valid, did you mean `:first-child` or `:nth-child(1)`?